# How do i run pyinstaller in windows environment

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

I don't understand at all how I can run pyinstaller in a Windows environment with Python 3.

For this moment I have tried the following.

1) `python3 -m pip install pypiwin32`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (223)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (223)
```

A moment ago i have had 220 version but it doesn't work as well.

2) `python3 -m pip install pip`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)
```

3) `python3 -m pip install pyinstaller`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (3.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (28.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2017.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: macholib>=1.8 in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph>=0.15 in c:\program files (x86)\python3\lib\site-packages (from macholib>=1.8->pyinstaller) (0.15)
```

4) `pyinstaller`

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

5) `pip`

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

6) `pypiwin32`

```
'pypiwin32' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Where are all these executables supposed to be?

Comment: Please properly format your post in the future. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Found,
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3\Scripts